# How I get ReplyMessage in Telegram Bot Api when use ReplyKeyboardMarkup?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I create a simple question->answer command.

Code write in Ruby

I send message to user like this:

```
HTTP.post(bot_send_message_uri, :json => {
                'chat_id'=> message['chat']['id'],
                'text'=> "You sure?",
                'reply_markup'=> {
                    'force_reply' => true,
                    'keyboard'=> [['Yes!'],['No!']],
                    'one_time_keyboard'=> true,
                    'selective'=> true
                }
            })
```

How can I find out how the user responded to the message?

Answer (score 0):

You can use inline keyboard from [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots#inline-keyboards-and-on-the-fly-updating).
Then you can get data sending from users using `update` object in telegram API.

Comment: Thanks for you response! It's a good solution. But I wanted create step-by-step bot like BotFather. And I think that better for UX is to use ReplyKeybordMarkup, maybe you have solution for it?

Comment: You can save user response in *lastcmd.txt* file, and in every step first read this file.